# help request speeding a code up

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

[image]I hope everybody is fine at Corona virus times.
Can anyone help me in speeding my code up for M=20?Thank you.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
 M = 1; \[Alpha] = 1.25; a = 0; b = 1;(**\[Beta]=0.7;**)
 \[Lambda]1 = ((t - a)*(b - s)^(\[Alpha] - 1) - (t - 
 s)^(\[Alpha] - 1))/Gamma[\[Alpha]]; \[Lambda]2 = (
 t*(b - s)^(\[Alpha] - 1))/Gamma[\[Alpha]];
 bb[0] = (Exp[3] - 1)/(Exp[3] + 2)*t;
 ww[0] = bb[0] /. t -> s;
 Table[
 D2 = 1/Gamma[2 - \[Alpha]]*
 Integrate[(s - \[Tau])^(
  1 - \[Alpha])*(D[ww[k] /. s -> \[Tau], {\[Tau], 2}]), {\[Tau], 
  a, s}, GenerateConditions -> False]; 
 DD[k] = Normal[
 Series[Simplify[D2 + D[ww[k], s] - 2*ww[k]], {s, 0, M}]]; 
 H[k + 1] = 
 Simplify[
 Integrate[\[Lambda]1*DD[k], {s, a, t}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]]; 
 G[k + 1] = 
 Simplify[
 Integrate[\[Lambda]2*DD[k], {s, t, b}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]]; 
 bb[k + 1] = Simplify[bb[k] + \[Beta]*(G[k + 1] + H[k + 1])]; 
 ww[k + 1] = Expand[bb[k + 1] /. t -> s], {k, 0, M}];
 u1 = Expand[bb[M] /. s -> t]
 0.864164 t + 0.0847467 t \[Beta] - 0.76272 t^1.25 \[Beta] + 
 0.677974 t^2.25 \[Beta]
 Expand[ FullSimplify[  1/Gamma[2 - \[Alpha]]*
 Integrate[(t - \[Tau])^(
 1 - \[Alpha])*(D[u1 /. t -> \[Tau], {\[Tau], 2}]), {\[Tau], a, t}, GenerateConditions -> 
 False] + D[u1, t] - 2*u1]]
 0.864164 - 1.72833 t - 0.779418 \[Beta] - 
 0.9534 t^0.25 \[Beta] - 0.169493 t \[Beta] + 1.72833 t^1. \[Beta] + 
 3.05088 t^1.25 \[Beta] - 1.35595 t^2.25 \[Beta]
 Integrate[%^2, {t, 0, 1}]
 0.248927 - 0.822165 \[Beta] + 0.711862 \[Beta]^2
 Plot[%, {\[Beta], 0, 1}]
```

Comment: normally `FullSimplify` takes very long time as it tries many thing. See what happens if you replace that with just `Simplify`

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2297406).

Comment: Dear Nassier;no progress.

Comment: How long does this take on your machine? This runs in ~20s on mine - how fast did you want it?

Comment: It goes twice as fast for me if you replace `alpha=1.25` with `alpha=5/4`. That way Mathematica will handle everything symbolically instead of using numerics - which I guess is faster in this case.

Comment: Dear bRost03, for M=20, ~20s?it is not possible.if it is ok, send me your code please.